# How to change session time out in opencart 2.X?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am using opencart version 2.1.0.1 and i wants change Admin session out time.

Basically i am looking for the solution for if system is idle from period of time then it should log out.

Thanks..

Comment: http://www.reboot.ro/troubleshooting/software/opencart-how-do-you-increase-the-session-timeout/

Comment: set `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '86400');` in `_construnct` method in file `system/library/session.php`

Comment: But this will set for my entire store and I don't want for store only for Admin login.